# Array of pointers in C++.

Tags: c++

I am not understanding the output of this ,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

// pointers and arrays 
char ch1 = 'a' ,  ch2= 'b';

char ch3[6] = {'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g' , 'h'};

char *ptr[3]; 

int main ()
{
    ptr[0] = &ch1 ;

    ptr[2] = ch3;
    cout << &ch1 << endl;
}
```

The out put is abcdefgh .

isn't &ch1 supposed to give the address of ch1  ? I cannot make sense why the output should be abcdefgh.

Comment: it's called undefined behavior

Comment: @ratchetfreak i cannot understand what array pointer is , its confusing .

Comment: then don't try to understand a faulty program you won't learn anything

Comment: The declaration and assignments to `ptr` do nothing and could be deleted without changing the behavior.

Comment: @kevincline Hard to say that for sure without seeing a dump of the executable. As @AustinMullins points out, one of the bytes of the address of `ch1` may actually be providing the NUL that terminates the "string" (although it is possible - but not guaranteed - that `ch3` would be followed by some zero bytes if `ptr` were not present).

Answer (score 7):

The expression `&ch1` does indeed produce the address of `ch1`. The reason you see `abcdefgh` printed is `cout` has a `char*` overload that prints the NUL-terminated string starting at the given address. In this case, it just so happens that `ch2`, `ch3`, and a NUL immediately follow `ch1` in memory so you get `abcdefgh` printed.

As @rachetfreak mentions, this is undefined behavior. It is illegal to access more than one character through `&ch1` because it is a pointer to a single character. On different platforms you may get different output, or a crash.

If you want to actually print the address of `ch1` you can cast it to `void*` so that `cout` won't assume it's a pointer to a string:

```
cout << (void*)&ch1 << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code shown, `ch1` and `ch2` are characters which are declared consecutively, and `ch3` is actually an array of characters. The `<<` operator interprets the address of `ch1` as a C-style string, which is just a pointer to a null-terminated character array. So, the interesting thing to me is that storing the address of `ch1` into `ptr[0]` results in a null character (the number 0) appearing in the byte after 'g`. As @AndrewMedico stated, this is compiler-specific behavior. I think the code was intended to show how C-strings are interpreted by IO streams, and how easy it is for bugs and security holes to creep in to otherwise good code.